# Android Customize picture on a DrawRect()

Tags: android, eclipse, bitmap, android-canvas, drawrect

How can I possibly set an **image** to my **drawRect()**? Is there anyway on how will I set **jpeg** or a **png** file to a paint then let it call on the drawRect parameters? tnx in advance. Please apologize a noob like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a bitmap based upon the rectangle information you have from a reference to the canvas that you are working with.  So if you are working within an onDraw( ) for example you can use [canvas.drawBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint)).

Update:
You could for instance do something like this with the information you were already using,

```
RectF rect = new RectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);
```

where the null for source is saying use the bitmap and null for paint says to just use the bitmap as the paint.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean i had been using drawRect() on my onDraw instead of drawBitmap(). heres the code:

     canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, background);